# How to reenable Java Preferences

Tags: macos, java

After installed JDK7, I disabled Java 1.6 in Java Preferences. Then I found the system cannot launch jars by new JDK 1.7, so I want to reenable 1.6, but I cannot relaunch preference again, it told me `No compatible version of Java 1.5+ is available.`

What should I do to bring it back?

Comment: What does `java -version` show in Terminal?

Comment: @Mark java version "1.7.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: What does the Java control panel in System Preferences and what exactly do you mean by " system cannot launch jars"

Comment: @Mark When I launch Java applications like umongo, it appears 'No compatible version of Java 1.6+ is available.'

Comment: Is the issue just packaged java .apps or running jars from the command line  as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer and will need adding to, mainly to show the change in Info.plist and an official reference for it.

It seems (from this [blog](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/)) that the structure or the Info.plist in running packaged Java apps has changed. The blog says in Mountain Lion but I would have the same issue in Lion, the issue is the change in Java.

Thus I can see two ways of running pakaged apps

1. Install java 1.6 from Apple (running Mongo.app uses this one for me)
2. Repackage the app using the suggested [AppBundler](http://java.net/projects/appbundler/)

Comment: Please, do you have a link for Mongo.app? And do you suggest repackaging Apple's outdated Java Preferences.app?

Comment: Do you mean [UMongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/)?

Comment: @GrahamPerrin - a misunderstanding I could not find umongo as in the OP's question but could find Mongo.app - now it is the other way round. Mountain Lion says Umongo.app is damaged and won't run. The answer is the same I think as Mongo.app was a packaged Java app